# There isn't package selection in lib on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

> When i was right clicking to lib, there isnt package selection. ** I
> am adding the picture of status. Can you help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAbQO.png)

I painted to this photo.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyTuL.png

How Can i find package selection? I need a package.

Answer (score 0):

To use packages in flutter you need declare them in the pubspec.yaml file, there you should see the list of packages you are using on the project.

Look at the documentation to read about how to use packages: [Using Packages in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages)